# Trying to add items to a TRadioGroup but no Item Editor or Items property is available

Tags: c++builder, radio-group, items

I'm trying to create a 4-button radio group on a Form using the `TRadioGroup` component. I can add the radio group, but I can't add any items to it.

The documentation gives two ways of doing this: the 1st way is to right-click the group box and select "Item Editor", and the 2nd way is to edit the `Items` property in the Object Inspector. However I have no Item Editor selection available on right-click, and no `Items` property in the Object Inspector.

Is there something in the setup that I've missed here, or will I have to resort to using a `TGroupBox` and adding individual `TRadioButton` control to it?

Comment: I just tested it in C++ Builder 10.3.3 and there is `Items` property in the object inspector. Look carefully or otherwise specify what version are you using.

Comment: I'm using "Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.3 Version 26.0.36039.7899". I just opened a new form and added a TRadioGroup component and looked in Object Inspector. I have the properties sorted alphabetically and they go .......... Hint, ItemIndex, Left. ........ There is no Items property on my sheet. It makes me think I have an overall setting that is required.

Comment: @AndrewBraithwaite Are you creating a VCL project or an FMX project? `TRadioGroup` in VCL definitely has a published [`Items`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TCustomRadioGroup.Items) property that should appear in the OI. Are you sure you are working with the *standard* `TRadioGroup` in the `Vcl.ExtCtrls` unit, and not a 3rd party `TRadioGroup`? Do you have any 3rd party packages installed that might be hiding/unregistering the `Items` property? If you run the IDE with the `-r` command-line switch and a clean config, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: @remylebeau I don't believe that I have any 3rd party packages installed. All I've installed is the Rad Studio package that I received from Embarcadero which it appears includes an Update 3. However when I ran it with the -r command-line switch, as you suggested, and started a new VCL project I did have an Items property in the OI. I am pretty sure I started this project as a VCL, I know I didn't select FireMonkey, but I'm not sure what an FMX project is. Is it possible to switch between them after creation? How can I see which version of Vcl.ExtCtrls I am using?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just created a new VCL Form within my project and when I added a TRadioGroup it again came up with no Items property.

Comment: @AndrewBraithwaite "*when I ran it with the -r command-line switch, as you suggested, and started a new VCL project I did have an Items property in the OI*" - well, then that suggests a configuration issue. You likely have a package installed that is interfering with the standard `TRadioGroup` component. You will likely have to uninstall packages one at a time until the `Items` property shows up correctly. Are you able to access `Items` in code at runtime? "*Is it possible to switch between [VCL and FMX] after creation?*" - no.

Comment: @AndrewBraithwaite "*How can I see which version of Vcl.ExtCtrls I am using?*" - I wasn't suggesting a wrong version of `Vcl.ExtCtrls` was being used. I was suggesting maybe a `TRadioGroup` from some unit other than `Vcl.ExtCtrls` might be used. If you drop a `TRadioGroup` on the Form and then select it in the code and do a Find Declaration, where does it lead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can't find any 3rd party packages installed but when I got a compilation error on a TRadioGroup component it directed to Vcl::ExtCtrls and not another package. Now I can't get a "Find Declaration" menu item either! I'm looking into this right now. I had previously installed C++Builder 2010 on this PC as well but it would never run, despite trying different run compatibility options, so I uninstalled it. Is it possible that something on that installation corrupted this one?

Comment: @AndrewBraithwaite not likely, as each version is designed to be independent from other versions, provided you installed them into separate folders.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I'll carry on trying to find out what is set in my installation that isn't set in the clean slate config. Thank you very much for your time and your help, I really do appreciate it.